# Indian with UAE resident visa expiring in 2 months while applying for Schengen Visa

Tags: indian-citizens, paperwork, schengen-visas, applications, uae

Me and my family are planning for a week long trip to Austria, Hungary & Czech Republic(max. no of stay).

We will be returning from there on October 28th, 2019 and my wife's UAE Resident Visa is expiring on January 1 2020(2 month validity as per the Checklist I have seen). But rest of the family got their visa till mid year of 2020.

Will this be a problem in the visa application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. The typical requirement is for a residence permit to be valid for at least 3 months beyond the return date of the trip to the Schengen Area. Eg see item 4 of https://www.mzv.cz/london/en/visa_and_consular_information/visa_information/schengen_visa/visa_up_to_90_days.html

Comment: Yes I have seen that. I tried to contact the Czech embassy and they asked to apply first as they cannot say it will be rejected or not. Having doubts if it will be waste of money to book everything just to apply and loose most of it by cancelling.